# Photoshop: How to edit color swatches?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Adobe Photoshop CS5, I can add, delete and rename swatches. However, I don't see an option to edit them. Is it possible to edit the color of an existing swatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it in simplest of words:

**No**

It's probably because it's a lot easier to just create a new colour than to create an option to edit colour values.

You can rearrange the order by going to Edit -> Preset Manager... -> Set Preset Type to "Swatches" -> Drag and drop the swatch to where you want it.

Comment: BloodPhilia! good to see you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use ["CLEAR SWATCHES" extension for Photoshop CC from Adobe Exchange](https://www.adobeexchange.com/store/products/1757).